# What are the methodologies used in hadoop bigdata?

Tags: hadoop

In one of the interview I  have been asked what methodology you are using in the hadoop project. Can any one please explain me in detail what are all the methodologies in hadoop development?

Comment: Methodology regarding what development ?

Comment: about hadoop-mapreduce with java

Comment: Do u want to know that implementation ...how to write a map reduce job using java?

Comment: I know mr job implementation. I just wants to know like software methodologies sprints,agile,waterfall, do the hadoop also have any kind of methodology while working as a team in hadoop project.

Comment: http://www.hadoopsphere.com/2012/11/delivery-methodology-for-hadoop-projects.html    refer this